# Search by selection option

Tags: php

I am currently busy with a project, I'm also new to this PHP scripting.

For example there is a category called 'football', also i've created a script where I can add items to the database. Now when I go to the category of 'football' I see an option like 'add a new item
this is how it shows:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Phcdu.png

But now I want to add a product some like 'Adidas or Nike' So I put 'Nike' @ Item and it will show all products of nike in the section of Football. But the problem is I don't receive anything:

```
<?php
include '../config.php';
if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['game'])) {
    $naame = $db->real_escape_string(trim($_POST['name']));
    $gaame = $db->real_escape_string(trim($_POST['game']));
    $query_90 = "SELECT * FROM log_items INNER JOIN log_game ON log_items.game = log_mobs.game WHERE log_items.name like '%$naame%' AND log_game.game = '" .$gaame. "' AND log_items.game = '" .$gaame. "'"
;

    $result_90 = $db->query($query_90) or die ($db->error());

    $n_90 = $result_90->num_rows;
    if($result_90 == 0) {
        echo 'no results';
    } else {
        while ($row_90 = $result_90->fetch_object()) {
            echo htmlspecialchars($row_90->name);
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: run the query with desired values instead of vars directly in mysql environment and see what it outputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the problem is in your query, you inner join `log_items` with `log_mobs` where the latter has not yet been introduced to the query.

I can only speculate on what your intention for the `log_mobs` table, but I will have a go at the query just the same.

```
$query_90 = "SELECT * FROM log_items 
            INNER JOIN log_mobs ON log_items.game = log_mobs.game
            INNER JOIN log_game ON log_items.game = log_game.game
            WHERE log_items.name like '%$naame%' 
            AND log_items.game = '" .$gaame. "'";
```

I removed the condition `AND log_game.game = '" .$gaame. "'` from the query because the modified query is already joining on that condition.

Also this code stinks like a bug to me.

```
$n_90 = $result_90->num_rows;
if($result_90 == 0) { 
    echo 'no results';
}
```

When I am sure intended to write:

```
if($n_90 == 0) { 
    echo 'no results';
}
```

The db library you are using looks like mysqli, look into using [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) over the [**real_escape_string**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) method.